# How to print Loop text string to New Text File

Tags: c#

I am creating an application that displays a table of Celsius from -40 - 40 and their Fahrenheit equivalents. I want the displayed text to be written to a text file.

I understand the loop but I just can't figure out how to print it to a text file.

This is my code so far:

```
for (int c = -40; c <= 40; c++)
{
    // Celsius convert to Fahrenheit //
    f = 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;

    // print into listbox //
    tempListBox.Items.Add("Celsius = " + c.ToString("n3") + " " + "Fahrenheit = " + f.ToString("n3"));
}
```

Comment: learn about `StreamWriter`?

Comment: Please at least show us your attempt at the text write, you haven't shown any effort at your actual problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string item in tempListBox)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you need to first include the following references at the top of your file...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then in your method, write your code like this...

```
        var tempOutputList = new List<string>();

        for (var c = -40; c <= 40; c++)
        {
            // Celsius convert to Fahrenheit//
            var f = 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;
            var tempOutputText = "Celsius = " + c.ToString("n3") + " " + "Fahrenheit = " + f.ToString("n3");

            tempOutputList.Add(tempOutputText);
            tempListBox.Items.Add(tempOutputText);
        }

        using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\tempFile.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string tempOutput in tempOutputList)
            {
                file.WriteLine(tempOutput);
            }
        }
```

Why this code is better, is that you are not using the 'items' in your ListBox, but rather a simple List with the property set to 'string'. Further investigation would reveal that you can also possibly bind your ListBox items to the list.  I'll leave that for you to figure out.